# multiple hosts and ssl certificates in jdk 1.8

Tags: ssl, sni, java-8

as we all know jdk 1.8 introduced support for sni on the server side.
my question is, haa anyone knowledge with it ?

my problem is as follows :

i run a custom java webserver.
it runs several sites on the same ip address.
some of these sites would need ssl. in a perfect world, i'd like to have one certificate per such site.
now i tried to check the shallow java documentation on sni, but it seems to only do help for validation, not certificate assignement...

to make things better all their classes are final and or package protected...

is it even possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's documented, but _choice_ of cert&key with matching name should happen automatically with the default KeyManager; see [sun.security.ssl.X509KeyManagerImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509KeyManagerImpl.java) at the `getAliases` overload with `List<SNIServerName> requestedServerNames` and the (nested) `CheckType.check` when `serverNames` is nonnull and nonempty. `SNIMatcher` allows you to reject connections when you don't have _any_ suitable cert.

Comment: Thanks for that... and how can you add several certificates ?Also for testing purposes, is it possible to use this strategy with several self signed certs ?

Comment: JSSE KeyManager is initialized from a KeyStore object, which usually (or by default) is loaded from a file. In the latter case use a keystore file that has multiple cert&key (privateKey) entries. If you write your own code have it create multiple PrivateKeyEntry's. Yes the certs can be selfsigned as long as they are accepted by the client(s); but note modern clients prefer and sometimes require SAN=SubjAltName extension (aka UCC) but some older tools used for selfsigning like openssl and keytool do not by default generate SAN, since long ago it was rare.